# How to get list of registered assemblies in IWindsorContainer (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, castle-windsor

How can I get list of assemblies (not classes, there may be multiple classes in one assembly) that were registered in an IWindsorContainer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var assemblies = container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof (object))
    .Select(handler => handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.Assembly)
    .Distinct();
```

This gets all of the registered handlers and then selects the assemblies that contain them.